# Add query parameter to current url in phtml

Tags: magento2, url, http-request

I want to add query parameter to my current url, I'm getting current url in my phtml like this:

```
$current_url = $this->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true]);
```

I want to add query parameter to my url so it will look like this:

> https://currenturl.com?new_query=123

And when the current url already has another query parameter, it will look like this:

> https://currenturl.com?old_query=22&new_query=123

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```
$current_url = $this->getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current' => true,'_use_rewrite' => true, '_query' => $your_query));
```

Where

```
 $your_query = array('new_query' => 123)
```

Comment: what is inside $your_query ?

Comment: It's works for me

Comment: Which file need to edit to add query param?

Comment: how can i get or echo the current url with the query parameter in phtml file?